# The best way to export private key as byte array

Tags: c#, private-key, x509certificate2

I write application that has to get private key from the user and then send it to another application as base64, I want to allow the user to insert a X509Certificate2 with the private key.
Now my bigproblem is how can I convert the private key from AsimetricAlgorithm object to bate array that contains all the private key?
I saw that I can use openSSl - convert all the certificate to pem file, and then to RSA file - and read the private key, but I dont want to use it because: I dont want to use on files, 3P library, it's not secure and so on..
does anyone know about another way to do that?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The `AsymmetricAlgorithm` object you get from the `PrivateKey` property of your `X509Certificate2` will in fact be an instance of one of the various types derived from `AsymmetricAlgorithm`, such as `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, `DSACryptoServiceProvider`, etc...

You will need to determine the type of private key you're dealing with, and cast it appropriately. Once cast, you should be able to call `ExportCspBlob(true)` to get the private key data.

Example (assuming an RSA key):

```
public string GetRSAPrivateKeyBase64(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    if (privateKey == null) throw new Exception("Not an RSA private key");
    // Export the CSP blob, including private key parameters 
    var cspBlob = privateKey.ExportCspBlob(true);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cspBlob);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's seems as wonderful solution, but, I have the source private key in pem file, and when I try to compare beteen the two keys, I see that they are diffrent... I dont know how .NET framwork export the blob, do you somtimes use this method? can you explain me how it works?

Comment: The CSP blob is a Windows specific binary representation of the key set which can be used with the ImportCspBlob function to initialize the encryption object. It is not going to be the PEM representation of the key. It seems that your question requires more detail as to exactly what you are trying to achieve if you are going to get a useful answer.